# styled-components with custom component not applying styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I tried the following code to style inner elements implemented by react-id-swiper:
https://kidjp85.github.io/react-id-swiper/

```
import Swiper from 'react-id-swiper';
import styled from 'styled-components';

    const MySwiper = ({ className, children }) => (
        <Swiper className={className} {...params}>
            {children}
        </Swiper>
    )
    
    const StyledMySwiper = styled(MySwiper)`
        .swiper-container{
            background-color: red !important;
        }
        .swiper-slide{
            background-color: red !important;
        }
        .swiper-wrapper{
            background-color: red !important;
        }
    `;
```

and then used it in my component:

```
function CustomSwiper(props) {
    return (
            <StyledMySwiper>
                <div>Slide #1</div>
                <div>Slide #2</div>
                <div>Slide #3</div>
                <div>Slide #4</div>
                <div>Slide #5</div>
            </StyledMySwiper>
    );
}

export default CustomSwiper;
```

But the styles are not applied.
what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `.h1` from the `StyledTestComponent`, custom styles will apply to the `TestComponent`.

```
const StyledTestComponent = styled(MyTestComponent)`
   {
    color: red;
    font-size: 100px;
  }
`;
```

If `TestComponent` has child like below,

```
function TestComponent({ className }) {
    return (
        <h1 className={className}>
          <div className='child'> test div element</div> //child
            aaaaasdfsdfsd
        </h1>
    );
}
```

You can use `div` tag or `className` for applying the styles,

```
 const StyledTestComponent = styled(MyTestComponent)`
    {
    color: red;
    font-size: 100px;
  } // This will apply to the main container

  .child {
    color: green;
    font-size: 100px;
  } // This will apply to child element
`;
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I override inner classes styles by class names?

Comment: for the child elements, you can use `className` or `tagname`. Updated the answer

Comment: Still not working, I have edited the example to show on the component I try to change the style of the inner elements